# connecting laptop to a monitor using hdmi-dvi cable

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a Lenovo ideapad330 and tried to connect it to an old monitor via hdmi-dvi cable but nothing happened. I tried to go to settings and update drivers but still nothing happened. Can someone help me with this issue? 
And also how do I configure HDMI onboard port to be the output port?

Comment: What OS does this run? The process might differ a bit depending on what OS and addons are installed. Thinkpads used to have a fn key combo for switching screen settings through a tool, but that may differ with ideapads

Comment: it uses an updated windows 10. I have also tried to switch screen in the settings but still nothing happened